# Create a notification filter in pubsub subscription in GKE

Tags: kubernetes, google-cloud-platform, google-kubernetes-engine, google-cloud-pubsub

How to create a notification filter in pub/sub subscription to select a particular message section in a JSON log.

For example:

- You have a JSON log:

```
{ 
 "incident_type": Bla bla",
 "incident_state": "Open",
 "message": GKE Cluster upgradinging, Can't perform update operation",
 "run": "Unsuccessful"

}
```

---

Tried this https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/how-to/cluster-notifications

---

Comment: You can filter only on PubSub message attributes. Not on the content.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you can use the subscription **filter**

> If a filter syntax is provided, subscribers will only receive messages
> that match the filter.

With **Golang**

```
import (
        "context"
        "fmt"
        "io"

        "cloud.google.com/go/pubsub"
)

func createWithFilter(w io.Writer, projectID, subID, filter string, topic *pubsub.Topic) error {
        filter := "attributes.author=\"unknown\""
        client, err := pubsub.NewClient(ctx, projectID)
        if err != nil {
                return fmt.Errorf("pubsub.NewClient: %v", err)
        }
        defer client.Close()

        sub, err := client.CreateSubscription(ctx, subID, pubsub.SubscriptionConfig{
                Topic:  topic,
                Filter: filter,
        })
        if err != nil {
                return fmt.Errorf("CreateSubscription: %v", err)
        }
        fmt.Fprintf(w, "Created subscription with filter: %v\n", sub)
        return nil
}
```

Ref : [Google doc](https://cloud.google.com/pubsub/docs/subscription-message-filter)

[image]